# There is a single pair $(a,b)$ such that $x^2+2(1+a)x+(3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2)=0$. For this pair, what is $a+b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

> There is a single pair $(a,b)$ such that $x^2+2(1+a)x+(3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2)=0$. For this pair, what is $a+b$?

I know how to find rational roots now because of my last question asked, but what about real roots? What do I do?

Comment: Do you mean *for a given $x$* there is such a pair $(a,b)$, and we don't care to find what that $x$ is?

Comment: Yes $\      \     \    \   \       $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0=x^2+2(1+a)x+(3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2) =\\(x+1+a)^2+(3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2-1-2a-a^2)
 =\\(x+1+a)^2+(2a^2+4ab+4b^2+1-2a)
=\\(x+1+a)^2+(a^2+4ab+4b^2)+(a^2-2a+1) \\
=(x+1+a)^2+(a+2b)^2+(a-1)^2
$$

Since
$$(x+1+a)^2+(a+2b)^2+(a-1)^2=0$$
you get
$$x+1+a=0\\
a+2b=0\\
a-1=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Completing squares, we have: $(x + a+1 )^2 + (a-1)^2 + (a+2b)^2 = 0$. Can you continue?